# HTML/JQuery - Body-width is not the same on all Browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I use this code:
"alert($('body').width());" to detect the Width of the body-element

and I found out that the body-width is not the same on different Browser,

- On Edge, the Width is: 1535px  (vertical Tabs activated)
- On Avast, the Width is: 1583px
- On Firefox, the Width is: 1583px
- On Opera, the Width is: 1545px (vertical Tabs activated)

The width is not the same on Opera and Edge, because on both Browsers are the "vertical Tabs activated", so if I deactivate the vertical Tabs on Edge, I get the same width like Avast or Firefox (1583px).

Would you please help me to detect, if a user has the "vertical Tabs activated" on his Browser and how to get the width of the "vertical Tabs"?

Comment: I believe it to be more of `extension`  related instead of a standard web pages.

Comment: Hello, many Thanks for your answer. I apreciate it.
I don't use any extension. The Edge and Opera have it as Standard. The User can activate it. I like the Tabs when they are vertical positioned on the left side, but unfortunately I found out, that the body width becomes smaller when the vertical tabs is activated

Comment: Why do you need to know the exact pixel width of the browser? If the site is built correctly using a responsive layout, then the site should automatically fill all available space and will amend its own layout depending on the available screen size.

Comment: Hello @RoryMcCrossan,
thank you for your answer, i appreciate it.
The issue, that i'm dealing with is, that the h1-element goes some pxs to the left side outside the section-element, if the "vertical Tabs  is activated". If this is activated, the width of the body becomes 1535px on "Edge-Browser" and 1545px on the "Opera-Browser" instead of 1583px, if this is deactivated.

You bring to think about the next solution:
 - should i create 2 "@media"s, one with min-width: 1535px and one with 1545px wide?

Is it a good idea?

Comment: In that case I would suggest you use % widths for your entire layout, instead of explicit px widths.

Comment: Hello @RoryMcCrossan,
thank you so much again for your answer. I tried it already, unfortunately it didn't work. At the end i fixed the problem using JQuery: 
"if (window.scrollY >=0){
   if ($('body').width() <= 1545)   {
    $('h1').css("right", Math.max(1585 - 5.6*window.scrollY, 1115)+ "px");}
    else {
         $('h1').css("right", Math.max(1585 - 5.6*window.scrollY, 1150)
        + "px");
   }   } "